# How to read Nodejs notification occur in CMD from jsp page using jquery/javascript

Tags: node.js, postgresql, jsp, cmd, real-time

I have an application which runs in `Tomcat` . I am making use of `servlet/jsp` and `postgresql` as database.

I am using `nodejs`  for real time notification for database entry.

I have referred the [TUTORIAL](http://bjorngylling.com/2011-04-13/postgres-listen-notify-with-node-js.html) and on database entry I am getting notification in `CMD`

How can I implement it in my jsp page , which means it should run in jquery/jsp. When notification comes I need an alert message.

How can I call the `CMD` notification inside jsp page in real time monitoring?

Refer my cmd result :

[image]

Suppose `page1.jsp` is my page.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to use LISTEN and NOTIFY. It's not at all easy to use that to drive asynchronous updates to a web page using JSP. You'd probably need a thread in the appserver that polled for notifications and dispatched ... well, I have no idea how the JSP part would work.

Comment: @CraigRinger can I use jQuery to listen in jsp page? I do not want to use ajax because it will spoil my network use.Is there possible to do with jsp/Servlet combination by using front end as jquery? Please suggest me if any alternative is there!!